# how to manage hardware of android cell phone

Tags: java, android

I am using Android emulator and development platform.

I have created a new application and wonder how can I close or open Android cell phone camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about opening it from your app you should use the camera Intent for that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

EDIT:

1 - is for the front-facing camera

Comment: If cell phone has two camera how can I distinguish ?

Comment: @coler'e I'm not sure what is your SDK version, but there's a "hack" for that. check the updated answer...

Comment: eestein, I am a bit confused about something. This is not related with this question. With Java service, I should write android control manager. The relationship between Java and Android, I do not understand. Your above code is Java or something else ? OR, IS Android application written with Java language ? I am a bit confused ?

Comment: @coler'e Android apps are Java-based. you can use other tools like mono or flex, but Android apps are natively java based.

Comment: I should eat something especially sugar based thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the AVD for your emulator, there are options for enabling front and back camera.  If you have enabled this option for your emulator, you will be able to access the camera just like you would on a regular phone (using the camera app, or via the system).

You probably didn't enable the camera option on your emulator image if you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you have enabled a camera on your emulator, and want to access it's functions yourself, instead of opening an existing camera application. You'll need to use functions in Android to actually access this hardware, and you'll also need to give the app permission to use it.

```
    private void startCamera(){
        //First check if a camera is available
            if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){ 
                Log.d("CameraApp", "It has a camera");
                Camera cam = Camera.open(); //Start using the camera. From here on out you should be able to access it's functions.     
                cam.unlock();
                cam.startPreview();
            } else {
                Log.d("CameraApp", "It does not have a camera");
                Toast.makeText(this, "No camera available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Be sure to close it when you're done.

```
    private void stopCamera(){
        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();
    }
```

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml to give your app permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Each function (zoom, autofocus, etc.) needs it's own permission to be added.

Also see this for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: I understand you have a camera class. But, in camera.open() method, what did you write ?

Comment: The camera class comes with Android. `import android.hardware.Camera;`. The documentation of this class is in the link I provided. Keep in mind that what I wrote is pretty basic. I suggest working of documentation mostly. Per example, I neglected to create a `SurfaceHolder` in the example.